# Can't sign into Google account or Facebook account after publishing app on the Google Play Store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook-login, google-signin

My app has been successfully published on the Google Play Store. However, I can't seem to login with either my Facebook account or Google account.

When I try to login with my Google account, nothing happens. But when I try to login with my Facebook account, I get: 
`Invalid key hash. The key hash does not match any stored key hashes.` I believe this could be the same issue with Google sign in.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you used released SHA key in firebase settings?

Comment: @NirajNiroula Fixed my problem. I had no idea Google Play Console would generate a new SHA key. Used the new key to fix my problem.